# Do I need my old passport for Canadian permanent residence application?

Tags: passports, canada, paperwork, residency

I am applying for Canadian PR and the form asks for my travel history of the last 10 years. Unfortunately, one of my old passports has been misplaced, although I do remember my travel dates. Do I need to submit the old passport as a proof. If it can't be located, what should I do?

Comment: I think permanent residence permit questions are on topic at expatriates SE but not here.